# Onion weed and soil sourness

Tags: soil, weed-control

Over the years I have had an ongoing battle with onion weed in my small front garden. I have poisoned and I have carefully dug out every bulb by hand (took forever), but to no avail. I tried using a weed mat, which worked for a while, but eventually the weeds made it through. I have a piece of old carpet which would cover the area, and I thought that if I put the carpet down, and then put gravel on top, that might work, but someone told me that it would make the soil go sour. I also thought about that black thick plastic you can get in Bunnings. Can you tell me if carpet or plastic would be a problem?

Answer (score 4):

@June welcome to the group!  Black plastic is something I have use and it works to control weeds.  It basically stops light from going through and hence prevents unwanted growth.  Make sure you cover the black plastic with tan bark so it says on the ground securely.

Comment: Does anyone know if either (or both) the carpet and the plastic would cause sour soil?

Comment: Old 100% wool carpet is commonly used as a weed mat at the bottom of a no dig garden  pile.